# mysql managing historical data

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, data-management

I have a mysql database that contains three pieces of data; time date stamp, temperature and location of sensor.  Every day I would like to maintain the data and only keep historical low,high and average temperature in my database from the past.  What functionality within mysql should I be looking at to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I would advise you to use MySQL scheduler and
trigger a stored procedure that would either:

1. clean up your table and leave only the low,high and average values;

   OR
2. move all relevant data (e.g. low,high and average values) to annother table which would then hold only that "relevant" data.

One other thing:
MySQL maybe isn't the best option for storing sensor data.
A NoSQL solution like Cassandra should be a better suited solution.

Maybe this could help You regarding that.

http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Comment: moving to another table was a thought which I didnt pursue.  Might venture down that road.  I will look into nosql also